# WebTryThreadLock crash on loadNibNamed

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiwebview

I encounter a crash that doesn't happen all the time but happens often enough to handle.

The `UITableViewCell` contains a `UIWebView`

I'm getting the following crash:
`bool _WebTryThreadLock(bool), 0x799b6480: Tried to obtain the web lock from a thread other than the main thread or the web thread. This may be a result of calling to UIKit from a secondary thread. Crashing now...`

The code that resulted the crash:
(on the viewcontroller)

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (indexPath.section == 0)
    {
       ...
    }
    else //section 1 - regular "feed" cells
    {
        FeedDataItem *item = [currentItemArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] ;
        FeedItemCell *cell = [self prepareCell:item rowIndex:indexPath.row tableView:tableView];
        return cell;
    }
}
```

`PrepareCell` is a service function that servers many classes like this one, and it starts with:

```
- (FeedItemCell *)prepareCell:(FeedDataItem *)item rowIndex:(long)rowIndex tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    FeedItemCell *cell = (FeedItemCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"FeedItemCell"];
    if (cell == nil)
    {
        NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"FeedItemCell" owner:self options:nil];  
        // <------- the crash is in the nib creation (the line above)  --------->
        cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
    }
    .....
}
```

I don't get it - what is done on the non main thread?
All the `reloadData` is under:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    [self.tableView reloadData];
});
```

(not related to the stack thread - just mentioned there is no loose reloadData involved)

Comment: Can you post the method that contains `dispatch_async` call?

Comment: well... they are not really related to the stack trace, just mentioned I am doing proper reloadData.